# Default contents of /etc/network/interfaces on Crunchbang/Debian?

Tags: networking

I've broken localhost on my computer. For example `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and `curl http://localhost:8000` don't work.

The contents of my /etc/network/interfaces is empty. Does anyone know what the default contents of this should be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Network Manager the default contents of the file `/etc/network/interfaces` is typically this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**NOTE:** That is from my Ubuntu 14.04 system, but Debian should be identical to this.

#### Where's it come from?

If you search to find out what package `/etc/network/interfaces` is a part of you'll find that it's not.

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/network/interfaces
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/network/interfaces
```

Rather it's generated by the postinstall script of the `ifupdown` package, specifically this script: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ifupdown.postinst`.

**NOTE:** You know it's a post install script for `ifupdown` based on its name and its location under the directory, `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.

*excerpt from script that generates interfaces file*

```
# Generic stuff done on all configurations
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] ; then
  # We don't need loopback interface definition anymore as
  # ifupdown handles loopback interface on its own from now
  if [ ! -f /etc/network/interfaces ] ; then
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
      echo "Creating /etc/network/interfaces."
      echo "# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)" > /etc/network/interfaces
      echo "# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:" >> /etc/network/interfaces
      echo "source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d" >> /etc/network/interfaces
    else
      report_warn "/etc/network/interfaces does not exist"
    fi
  fi
fi
```

#### References

- [What's the default /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214170/whats-the-default-etc-network-interfaces)
- [/etc/network/interfaces has no package owner?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/etc-network-interfaces-has-no-package-owner-937023/)
- [how to read installation scripts in debian apt suite?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-distributions-5/how-to-read-installation-scripts-in-debian-apt-suite-940836/)

Comment: Awesome thanks. Got it working. Thought I was going to have to reinstall Linux! For anyone else who encounters this problem you also needed to restart the network-manager. `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`

Comment: This is such a beautiful answer.

Comment: @dotancohen - thank you for your kind words, then mean a lot!